# HtmltoPDF 64 bit version dlls

Tags: c#, asp.net, wkhtmltopdf

I found this [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) project to convert html to pdf. But I am unable to locate the 64 bit dlls for Windows. Can some one point me where to find the 64 bit dlls for wkhtmltopdf

Answer (score 1):

Currently there are no 64 bit versions of the dll.

You can run the project in a 32 bit app pool (i am assuming that you are using iis).

Answer (score 1):

you can use [Tues Pechkin](https://github.com/tuespetre/TuesPechkin) to Convert  html to pdf. It runs both in 32 and 64 bit envoirnment